# Sometimes empty post object - Joomla JRequest::get( 'post' );

Tags: javascript, joomla

I am using a form to transmit data from a online game. But very strangly sometimes the post object is empty??? the form is submitted by javascript and a value is set.

After click every 3-5 times the transmitted form is empty in the "post" object. I Am using this code in a MVC in a custom joomla component.

```
 <form method="post" action="/index.php?option=com_findme&amp;view=pair&amp;Itemid=40&    amp;lang=de" id="pair" name="pair">
<div class="ImagesSecondRow">
<div class="ImagePaneSmall">
<input type="image" onclick="mysubmit('clickeditem','1382378814')" value=""     src="http://www.dualda.com/media/com_findme/userimages/2356/thumbs/2356.jpg" onmouseout="outUserimage()" ;="" onmouseover="overUserimage('http://www.dualda.com/media/com_findme/userimages/2356/thumbs/2356.jpg')" class="ImagesInputPair" id="thumbimages" name="thumbimages">

</div>

<div class="ImagesSecondRow">
<div class="ImagePaneSmall"> 
<input type="image" onclick="mysubmit('clickeditem','1382377841')" value="" src="http://www.dualda.com/media/com_findme/userimages/1383/thumbs/1383.jpg" onmouseout="outUserimage()" ;="" onmouseover="overUserimage('http://www.dualda.com/media/com_findme/userimages/1383/thumbs/1383.jpg')" class="ImagesInputPair" id="thumbimages" name="thumbimages">
</div>

<div class="ImagesSecondRow">

<input type="image" onclick="mysubmit('clickeditem','1382378691')" value="" src="http://www.dualda.com/media/com_findme/userimages/2233/thumbs/2233.jpg" onmouseout="outUserimage()" ;="" onmouseover="overUserimage('http://www.dualda.com/media/com_findme/userimages/2233/thumbs/2233.jpg')" class="ImagesInputPair" id="thumbimages" name="thumbimages"></div>

<div class="ImagesSecondRow">
<div class="ImagePaneSmall">
<input type="image" onclick="mysubmit('clickeditem','1382378778')" value="" src="http://www.dualda.com/media/com_findme/userimages/2320/thumbs/2320.jpg" onmouseout="outUserimage()" ;="" onmouseover="overUserimage('http://www.dualda.com/media/com_findme/userimages/2320/thumbs/2320.jpg')" class="ImagesInputPair" id="thumbimages" name="thumbimages">    </div>
</div>

<div class="ImagesSecondRow"><div class="ImagePaneSmall"><input type="image" onclick="mysubmit('clickeditem','1382379029')" value="" src="http://www.dualda.com/media/com_findme/userimages/2571/thumbs/CU7WyX4Z.jpg" onmouseout="outUserimage()" ;="" onmouseover="overUserimage('http://www.dualda.com/media/com_findme/userimages/2571/thumbs/CU7WyX4Z.jpg')" class="ImagesInputPair" id="thumbimages" name="thumbimages"></div>

<input id="clickeditem" type="hidden" value="" name="clickeditem"> 
<input type="hidden" value="1394821467" name="timekey">

<input type="hidden" value="0" name="timeout">
<input type="hidden" value="0.516067" name="pageloadtime">
<input type="hidden" value="com_findme" name="option">
<input type="hidden" value="pair" name="view">

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">


    function overUserimage(userimg){

    if (document.images)

      document.images["emptyuser"].src = userimg
     }

function outUserimage(){
   if (document.images)
      document.images["emptyuser"].src = "images/findme/empty_user.png"
}


        function mysubmit(elementname,value)
        {
            //�ndern des formular elements
            document.getElementById(elementname).value = value;
            //alert(elementname + ': ' +      document.getElementById(elementname).value);

            document.pair.submit();
        }


 </script>
```

After transmitting I check the variable by using JRequest::getVar. but sometimes they are correct and sometimes empty

Comment: what version of Joomla?

Comment: 1.5 - sadly i know it is old

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardware limitation.

I had the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78066042/post-is-sometimes-empty-and-sometimes-not-empty/)

If you check the error logs, you should see

```
PHP Warning:  Unknown: Unable to create temporary file, Check permissions in temporary files directory. in Unknown on line 0 
PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST data can't be buffered; all data discarded in Unknown on line 0
```

More information on that error can be found [here](https://www.kopf.com.br/kaplof/how-to-fix-php-warning-unknown-post-data-cant-be-buffered-all-data-discarded-in-unknown-on-line-0/)

Sorry this answer came 10 years too late. I found this post while I was trying to solve it myself.